# Send Outlook 2010 E-mail via Powershell

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

1st of all, in my job, we do not have an Active Directory, and it won't change so soon.

What I am trying to do is, send an e-mail to desired users using HTML.
I have this script that I wrote:

```html
#Variables
$sig = Get-Content "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Assinaturas\html.htm"
$Para = "mail@domain.com.br"
$Assunto = "Teste"
$Conteudo="<html>
<head>
<style>
<!--
@font-face {font-family:Calibri; font-size:11.0pt;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
Line1
<br><br>
&emsp;line 2
<br><br>
&emsp;line 3
<br><br>
<strong><em>Line 4</strong></em>
<br>
Atenciosamente,
<br>
</body>
</html
$sig
"

#Writedatbitchdown
$outl = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$email = $outl.CreateItem(0)
$email.display()

$email.To = $Para
$email.Subject = $Assunto

$oldbody = $email.HTMLBody
$newbody = $Conteudo
$newbody += $oldbody
$email.HTMLBody = $newbody

Start-Sleep -s 3
$email.Send()
Start-Sleep -s 5
#Quit
$outl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($outl)
Remove-Variable outl
```

As you can see, I tried to add signature using Get-content "signatureFile.htm", it doesn't work at all, tried to use default signature and it doesn't work either. I received the e-mail as plain text.

[image: Example]

Another situation is the e-mail is sent as HTML and ONLY the image is not shown up.

How can I link signature and its images with Outlook 2010?
If theres anything not clear, please comment it out and I will try to express myself better.

Answer (score 0):

If a user already had signature assigned to new emails this code should have worked on its own without `$sig`. That being said you are trying a add a signature from file which does work with an important change which is the way you are referencing the environment variable `%userprofile%`. PowerShell does not expand those as is in scripts. The PowerShell way is to use the `env:` keyword. Consider the following

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> Get-ChildItem env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\mcameron\AppData\Roaming
```

In your case your `$sig` should be something like this:

```
$sig = Get-Content "$($env:appdata)\Microsoft\Signatures\Logo.htm"
```

As for embedding the image I am not sure at this time but will investigate. As a side note I don't understand the reason for the comment about ActiveDirectory?

Comment: The AD comment was cause all the tutorials about how to create a link between Outlook and Signature files get all the information from the AD.
Thanks for the answer, I will test this right now.

Comment: I didn't worked out... My e-mail is sent just perfect, all the fonts and colors just right as it looks in the original signature, but when the user receives it looks like plain text (like the image in this question), even if I configure the account to read e-mails in HTML mode.